# Struts2 DOJO anchor tag does not displaying as link, why?

Tags: struts2, dojo

I am trying to use struts2 dojo anchor tag on Jsp.

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

    <sx:head/>

    <sx:a href="www.google.com"> Email Link</sx:a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am trying to use Struts2 DOJO anchor tag(<sx:a />) but it is not displaying on page. As it working fine when we use tag (<s:a/>).

Comment: Struts2 DOJO is deprecated, drop it.

Comment: Why do you need dojo for simple url? Try to write full url with `http://`.